# Nokogiri Gem Error Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I searched around Stack Overflow and read few web pages and tried out method from Nokogiri website with Macports and HomeBrew, but still nothing.

```
 gem install nokogiri 
 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
 Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/.autotest
```

So, I had to use sudo command to see if I could install it.

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit 
http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing
dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
--with-zlib-dir
--without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include
--without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib
--without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--with-iconv-dir
--without-iconv-dir
--with-iconv-include
--without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
--with-iconv-lib
--without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
--with-xml2-dir
--without-xml2-dir
--with-xml2-include
--without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
--with-xml2-lib
--without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
--with-xslt-dir
--without-xslt-dir
--with-xslt-include
--without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
--with-xslt-lib
--without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
--with-libxslt-config
--without-libxslt-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-libxml-2.0-config
--without-libxml-2.0-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-libiconv-config
--without-libiconv-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-iconvlib
--without-iconvlib
--with-iconvlib
--without-iconvlib
--with-iconvlib
--without-iconvlib
--with-iconvlib
--without-iconvlib


 Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9 for
 inspection.
 Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

It looks like libxml and libexslt that were included in my Mac ARE working while libiconv isn't. Just to give perspective, I was originally trying to use RSpec, but that had errors with capybara, which was not possible because nokogiri was not working.

Thanks to anyone who has suggestions. Like I said, Homebrew didn't work - and I don't plan on re-installing OS because installing Rails 3 itself was quite annoying in my case.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the instructions on the page in the error message http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html.
There is a section on installing the dependencies with homebrew.

Comment: Please install Ruby 2.0 (or even 1.9.3) using http://rvm.io instead of using Ruby 1.8. You'll run into many problems with Ruby 1.8 with using recent gems. http://rvm.io has many articles on troubleshooting install, which will also help.

Comment: Did you install libiconv as the error says?

Comment: at TrondHatlen: I did. I was able to install libxml and libexsit, but I could not link them (something about running them parallel?). at Dogbert: I couldn't update my Ruby....I'm running 32-bit Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and for some reason, it doesn't let me get past Ruby 1.8.7, and I gave up on RVM because that didn't work for me (tried like 10 times no lies). And at santhosh: I tried! But for some reason, it doesn't install saying libiconv is already in my Mac (I think it's included in the Mac?)